# Mac Dual Monitor without apple menu bar and Prevent Second monitor to go black while one is fullscreen, is possible?

Tags: display, macbook, fullscreen, system-preferences

I spend long hours working on my macbook and usually use a second monitor on which I put youtube videos (fullscreen) to pass the time while I work.

It has always bothered me that the apple menu bar appears on the second monitor, I have managed to disable the apple menu bar from the Mission Control preferences but when doing fullscreen with youtube, quicktime, etc. the other monitor goes black

Is there a method to remove the apple menu bar on the second monitor and at the same time prevent the other monitor from going black when doing fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

This is an either/or situation.

You can prevent the menu bar appearing on the second screen by setting System Prefs > Mission Control > Displays have separate Spaces to *off*

This, will, however, mean your other screen will go black if you invoke fullscreen.

If you *enable* Displays have separate Spaces you lose the back screen… & gain a menu bar - though only if you hit the top of the screen with your cursor.